# How to replace a current ffmpeg command with another without stopping the broadcast

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to know if I can replace a current ffmpeg command with another without stopping the broadcast.
I explain
I have this ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg   -stream_loop -1  -i myvideo1   -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast  -c:a copy  -f flv rtmp://myoutputlive
```

Now if I want to make another scene with ffmpeg after some times

```
ffmpeg   -stream_loop -1  -i sound   -i  image.png   drawtext  drawbox    -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast  -c:a copy  -f flv rtmp://myoutputlive
```

How to replace the first ffmpeg command by the new without down the broadcast?

Comment: The (a)zmq or (a)sendcmd filters may do what you want.

Comment: Thanks I'll check the documentation.